# "Are you able to" vs "Can you" vs "Could you" vs "Would you"

Tags: modal-verbs, word-difference, politeness

I don't know what the differences are between these phrases:

1. Are you able to ...
2. Would you be able to ...
3. Can you ...
4. Could you ....
5. Would you ....

I am particularly interested in knowing which phrase is best to use when making a request to a superior person at a work place. 
What if a manager wants their employee to do something for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that "Can you" and "Could you" were fairly informal - "Could you throw me that teatowel?"
"Would you" is a polite request - "Would you come this way please?". 
I think one of the first two would be best when asking a superior to do something for you, or "Would you mind doing X?"